# Running projects fails due to packages

Tags: go, module, package

I had a working project in Go which was not using Go modules but I decided to start using them today. So I went ahead and ran :

go mod init

Everything went fine with that so I did a few changes to some method and I tried to run it and then it failed with this error :

[image]

and now my project does not run.

What does this error mean?

Note : I know text is preferable over images but I cannot copy the error as its inside a VM. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score -3):

Well I found out what the issues was by randomly roaming through forums.
The solution is setting this environment variable :

```
GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org
```

And problem solved.
Thanks everyone.